# Is it possible to use the YouTube API to automatically create a comment when a new YouTube video is uploaded?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a personal program to use with my Google account. I don't have a custom website or domain to use. Basically, the idea of my request was to create a personal bot that would comment "First" on a video as a joke between my friends. I looked into the YouTube API a bit, but I got differing answers on the capabilities of the v3 data API. I found the commentThread page but am also confused about its usage. If anyone could give me a basic idea on if this project is possible, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

As you said, you want to create a comment when a video uploaded. YouTube has provide the webhooks for this.

You can see the docs [push_notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). I think that is what you want. :)